# Carriage Returns as a field entry Access 2007 VBA

Tags: sharepoint, excel, ms-access-2007, carriage-return, vba

I have a form in Excel that I'd like to update a SharePoint list with.  I found the easiest/legal/feasible way is to link the SharePoint list into an Access database and update it from Excel.  I've gotten it to update the list, but I can get Access to retain my carriage returns.  I've tried vbCrLf , Chr(13) & Chr(10), and /n (C - syntax obviously did not work).  I've tried writing them as is, and with "" but with "" it writes them verbatim (of course)..  I've tried adding the carriage returns into the variable and into the string to create the field.  I'm stuck!  Here's a snippet of my code:

```
 ProblemStatement = txtProblem.Value & vbCrLf
    SolutionStatement = txtSolution.Value & vbCrLf
    Set oAcc = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    'Open Database in Microsoft Access window
     oAcc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Documents and Settings\ecook\MyDocuments\NoneArchived.accdb", True

    oAcc.Visible = False

    'Create a Recordset based on <Table name>
    Set rstTable = oAcc.CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("NoneArchived")
    With rstTable
      .AddNew
        ![PrintedPassdown] = ProblemStatement & _
        SolutionStatement & _
        Maintenance
        ![ToolSet] = ToolSet
        ![Tool] = Chamber

      .Update
    End With


    oAcc.Application.Quit
    Set oAcc = Nothing
Workbooks(MyWorkbook).Activate
```

I also have the problem of Access app not closing.  The db closes, but not the application... FUN!   I would really appreciate your help.  CookieCoder

Comment: Have you tried vbNewline? Also Access is not closing because the recordset is still open. Close the recordset and set it to nothing and then try again.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have the application left from previous failed runs? It is rarely a good idea to develop with visible = false. I tested your code, and it works for me, including the carriage returns, although I did just use scratch text. The application is not still running at the end, as you would expect.

Comment: @Remou: Good point regarding the 'previous failed runs'

Comment: I ended up adding a "< br/>" and it worked! I did a replace function for this button only. I also broke the update function into its own subroutine to break the variable relationship which was causing the Access application to hang open.

Comment: @CookieCoder, sounds like you found a fix. Go ahead and add that as the answer.